# New folders on desktop not appearing where expected

Tags: icons, directory, ubuntu-mate

I keep running into an irksome problem with the Ubuntu Mate desktop.  (I am currently using 17.10.)  The problem is that whenever I create a folder on the desktop (right click->create folder) the folder often appears somewhere far away from where I right clicked.  Often, but not always, the new folder is in the upper-left corner---especially if nothing is in that area.

I would expect the folder to appear relatively close to my cursor, and it often does (even if there are a bunch of other icons around it).  I am especially puzzled when this happens and there are no icons anywhere near where I right click on the screen.

So, my question is:  Is this the intended behavior?  If so, what rules govern where to place the new folder?

Comment: @waltinator Mate is an official falvour: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the comment.  Does this happen with all flavors of Ubuntu?  How could I know that _a priori_?

Comment: it was a comment to waltinator - that later deleted his comment.